# Live update PHP variable from input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel

I'm trying to put the text from an input (name is 'motd') into my php script ($text). 
All stack-overflow answers say to put `$text = 'echo $_POST['motd'];'` but this does not work. My laravel page fails to load.

Ultimately Im trying to add the input text into a PHP form using . I have included the big script below.

The Controller: https://github.com/Pterodactyl/Panel/blob/develop/app/Http/Controllers/Server/ServerController.php

Thanks.

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="#motd" id="motd">
<!-- motd (server) -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="card card-inverse bg-space-600 m-b-10">
         <div class="card-block"> 
           <div class="minecraft" id="motd-preview">

            <?php
            require (app_path().'/Http/Colors.php');

            use \System\Http\Colors;

            $text = 'The Text I want to Show';

            echo Colors::convertToHTML($text);

            echo Colors::clean($text);
            ?>
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group p-b-35">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
     <label class="font-size-15" class="font-size-15" for="motd">MOTD</label>  
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="breadcrumb-toggle" id="toggle-color-codes">
       <i class="wb-chevron-down-mini"></i>
     </a>      
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"> 
    <span class="pull-right"> 
      <input type="textbox" name="motd" id="motd-raw" class="maxlength-input form-control d-inline-block w-200" data-plugin="maxlength" data-placement="top-right" maxlength="20" value="The Text I Want to Move" />  
     </span>
  </div> 
</div>          
</form>
```

```js
<?php

namespace System\Http;

class Colors {
 const REGEX = '/(?:§|&amp;)([0-9a-fklmnor])/i';
 const START_TAG  = '<span style="%s">';
 const CLOSE_TAG  = '</span>';
 const CSS_COLOR  = 'color: #';
 const EMPTY_TAGS = '/<[^\/>]*>([\s]?)*<\/[^>]*>/';
 const LINE_BREAK = '<br />';
 static private $colors = array(
  '0' => '000000', //Black
  '1' => '0000AA', //Dark Blue
  '2' => '00AA00', //Dark Green
  '3' => '00AAAA', //Dark Aqua
  '4' => 'AA0000', //Dark Red
  '5' => 'AA00AA', //Dark Purple
  '6' => 'FFAA00', //Gold
  '7' => 'AAAAAA', //Gray
  '8' => '555555', //Dark Gray
  '9' => '5555FF', //Blue
  'a' => '55FF55', //Green
  'b' => '55FFFF', //Aqua
  'c' => 'FF5555', //Red
  'd' => 'FF55FF', //Light Purple
  'e' => 'FFFF55', //Yellow
  'f' => 'FFFFFF'  //White
 );
 static private $formatting = array(
  'k' => '',                               //Obfuscated
  'l' => 'font-weight: bold;',             //Bold
  'm' => 'text-decoration: line-through;', //Strikethrough
  'n' => 'text-decoration: underline;',    //Underline
  'o' => 'font-style: italic;',            //Italic
  'r' => ''                                //Reset
 );
 static private function UFT8Encode($text) {
  //Encode the text in UTF-8, but only if it's not already.
  if (mb_detect_encoding($text) != 'UTF-8')
   $text = utf8_encode($text);
  return $text;
 }
 static public function clean($text) {
  $text = self::UFT8Encode($text);
  $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
  return preg_replace(self::REGEX, '', $text);
 }
 static public function convertToMOTD($text, $sign = '\u00A7') {
  $text = self::UFT8Encode($text);
  $text = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $text);
  $text = preg_replace(self::REGEX, $sign.'${1}', $text);
  $text = str_replace("\n", '\n', $text);
  $text = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $text);
  return $text;
 }
 static public function convertToHTML($text, $line_break_element = false) {
  $text = self::UFT8Encode($text);
  $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
  preg_match_all(self::REGEX, $text, $offsets);
  $colors      = $offsets[0]; //This is what we are going to replace with HTML.
  $color_codes = $offsets[1]; //This is the color numbers/characters only.
  //No colors? Just return the text.
  if (empty($colors))
   return $text;
  $open_tags = 0;
  foreach ($colors as $index => $color) {
   $color_code = strtolower($color_codes[$index]);
   //We have a normal color.
   if (isset(self::$colors[$color_code])) {
    $html = sprintf(self::START_TAG, self::CSS_COLOR.self::$colors[$color_code]);
    //New color clears the other colors and formatting.
    if ($open_tags != 0) {
     $html = str_repeat(self::CLOSE_TAG, $open_tags).$html;
     $open_tags = 0;
    }
    $open_tags++;
   }
   //We have some formatting.
   else {
    switch ($color_code) {
     //Reset is special, just close all open tags.
     case 'r':
      $html = '';
      if ($open_tags != 0) {
       $html = str_repeat(self::CLOSE_TAG, $open_tags);
       $open_tags = 0;
      }
      break;
     //Can't do obfuscated in CSS...
     case 'k':
      $html = '';
      break;
     default:
      $html = sprintf(self::START_TAG, self::$formatting[$color_code]);
      $open_tags++;
      break;
    }
   }
   //Replace the color with the HTML code. We use preg_replace because of the limit parameter.
   $text = preg_replace('/'.$color.'/', $html, $text, 1);
  }
  //Still open tags? Close them!
  if ($open_tags != 0)
   $text = $text.str_repeat(self::CLOSE_TAG, $open_tags);
  //Replace \n with <br />
  if ($line_break_element) {
   $text = str_replace("\n", self::LINE_BREAK, $text);
   $text = str_replace('\n', self::LINE_BREAK, $text);
  }
  //Return the text without empty HTML tags. Only to clean up bad color formatting from the user.
  return preg_replace(self::EMPTY_TAGS, '', $text);
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please provide the controller code

Comment: `$text = $_POST['motd'];`and `value="<?php echo $text;?>"`

Comment: $text = $_POST['motd'];  - is this not working?

Comment: @FrozenSnow: You want to get it into controller?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks. this breaks my page though.

Comment: @manian unfortunately not :(

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan Yes! I think thats what I should look into more. Any ideas what to search?

Comment: So you can get your text field value into controller by doing some code into controller if you like then i can write an answer

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan Okay. I'd love an answer :)

Comment: @SapneshNaik @ MuhammadRizwan I have added my PHP code to the page.

Comment: @FrozenSnow: Include your controller code also

Comment: are you even using laravel?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan Added the Controller link, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get your text input value into your controller like this:

```
public function someName(Request $request) {
     dd($request->motd) // this is test either you get value from form text field or not
}
```

Be ensure to use `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your controller.

Comment: Wow thanks! does not seem to work, hope seeing the controller can fix this. Added the link above. Also, how would I then use the requested value in my PHP form?

Comment: ` public function getRawMOTD(Request $request, $uuid) 
 {
  $server = Models\Server::getByUUID($uuid); 
  
     dd($request->motd) // this is test either you get value from form text field or not
 }`

this getting closer? still breaks the page though

Comment: The page says "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: I do not see an error unfortunately. The page just does not load :/

Comment: It looks you have some other problem ..why action="#motd" in your form?

Comment: Here's an error from the log: production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: Oh, another attempt I made. That no longer has a use, I will remove it.

Comment: the page loads fine without the added controller code?

Comment: are you getting the data into your controller?

Comment: I'm not sure really :/

Comment: at looking into your code, it seems confusing what are you trying to get and where